# Overriding method with generic return type in Java

Tags: java, generics, subclassing, return-type

When using generics in the return type, I'm having trouble extending a parent class 
like following example.

As you know, without generics, the following example will be compiled normally, but it won't be type safe because it's type should be Object.

Is there any clear solution (or pattern, or advice, anything will be helpful!) that I can refer to?

```
class AbstractReader<T>{
    public abstract T readNext();
}
class ByteArrayReader extends AbstractReader<byte[]>{
    @Override
    public byte[] readNext(){   /*...*/ }
}
class StringReader extends ByteArrayReader {
    @Override
    public String readNext() {  
        /* The return type is incompatible 
           with ByteArrayReader.readNext()! */
        return new String(bytes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that there it doesn't make sense for `StringReader` to extend `ByteArrayReader`. You have confused inheritance with composition.

When `StringReader` inherits from `ByteArrayReader` you are saying that it will fulfill a contract that says it has a `readNext` method that returns a `byte[]`.

What you really want to do is use *composition* rather than inheritance:

```
class StringReader extends AbstractReader<String> {
    private AbstractReader<byte[]> downstream;

    public StringReader(AbstractReader<byte[]> downstream) {
        this.downstream = downstream;
    }

    public String readNext() {
        return new String(downstream.readNext());
    }
}
```

This `StringReader` fulfills the `AbstractReader<String>` contract, and is implemented in terms of a downstream `AbstractReader<byte[]>`. Note that it does not explicitly require a `ByteArrayReader` - any old `AbstractReader<byte[]>` will work.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that the StringReader is AbstractReader<String>. (And polymorphism won't work right if my code compiled successfully.) But if StringReader and ByteArrayReader share many functions, you will see codes like `ReturnType someMethod(Args args){ byteArrayReader.someMethod(args); }` repetitively. Isn't it weird?

Comment: Yes, it is a little weird. What you're essentially doing here is mapping an `AbstractReader<TypeA>` to an `AbstractReader<TypeB>`, so you (unfortunately) need to implement every method. You *could* achieve this using reflection if there's a simple way to map the type parameters, but it would be slow, ugly and completely unmaintainable.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Decorator Design Pattern instead of inheritance:

```
class StringReader {
    private ByteArrayReader bar;

    public StringReader(ByteArrayReader bar) {
        this.bar = bar
    }

    public String readNext() {
        return new String(this.bar.readNext());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I also think using composition is the best in this case. However, if StringReader and ByteArrayReader share many methods, the Decorator will have repetitive codes like this:

`ReturnType someMethod(Arg args){ byteArray.someMethod(); }`

Will this be inevitable?

Comment: Yes, it would likely result in repetitive code, but would also result in a cleaner implementation!

Answer (score 0):

What your problems are trying to tell you is that this isn't a good use of inheritance. A StringReader definitely doesn't have an is-a relationship to a ByteArrayReader. If there's some functionality in common between them, that's merely an implementation detail. Any such common code should be pushed up to AbstractReader from which both should extend directly. Then the abstract class correctly contains code common to its subclasses and StringReader and ByteArrayReader are correctly unrelated besides being implementations of the same thing (presumably a Reader).

Comment: Thanks. My sample code was confusing, but I could find out the problem from your answer.